# Uploading SQLite database located on android device to a cloud service(amazon)

Tags: java, sqlite, amazon-web-services, android-sqlite

I am trying to figure out how I would send a local SQLite database file that is created on runtime of my android app and send that database file to a cloud service so it can have that database in the cloud and I can fetch data from it.

I have already gotten my app to store SQLite database information on the device it self, but now I want to use Amazon Web Services for backing up my database onto those server.

Any tips,help, comments or suggestion are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this database behind a web server or is it embedded in the Andriod app?

Comment: the SQLite database in created inside the App upon launching the app. so i guess it is embedded.